# Numpy and dot products of multiple vector pairs: how can it be done?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I want to get `dot product` of N vector pairs (a_vec[i, :], b_vec[i, :]).

`a_vec` has shape `[N, 3]`, `bvec` has the same shape (N 3D vectors).

I know that it can be easily done in cycle via `numpy.dot` function. But cannot it be done somehow simpler and faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`np.einsum` would do it:

```
np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a_vec, b_vec)
```